# Почему мой код все время пытается создать одну и ту же папку?

Tags: php

Я пытаюсь создать форму регистрации на PHP, в которой данные пользователя, указанные при регистрации, будут сохраняться для каждого пользователя в отдельный каталог. Завис из за того, что mkdir создает 2 папки а потом просто ругается на то что папка уже существует. Подскажите, что делаю не так и куда копать дальше.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Регистрация</title>
</head>
<body><?php 
if(empty($id)){
       $id=1;
    }
    if(is_dir('../users/id'.$id))
    {
      $id++;
      echo "Папка существует";
    }
    else{
        echo "Папка не существует";
    }
    echo $id;
    mkdir('../users/id'.$id,0777, true);
    ?>
    <form action="registration" method="POST">
        <input class="logininput" name="username" type="text">
        <input class="logininput" name="password" type="text">
        <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="<?php $id ?>">
        <input type="submit" value="Регистрация">
    </form>
    <?php
    
    print_r($_POST);
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    $user=$username.'&'.$password."\n";
    $userpath='../users/id'.$id.'/user.txt';
    file_put_contents($userpath, $user,FILE_APPEND);
       if (file_exists($userpath)){
        echo "Пользователь записан";
       }
    else 
    {
        echo "Пользователя не существует";
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ну а зачем пытаться создавать одинаковые папки? А в целом проблема не ясна - что надо то решить? Какую проблему?

Comment: `if(empty($id)){` --- что делает это условие? оно заведомо всегда `true`  Может там имелась в виду проверка `$_POST['userid']`?

Comment: Также стоит упомянуть, что, очевидно, `mkdir` надо делать только тогда, когда папки не существует.......а не при любых условиях

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну очевидно же, что ему не нужны одинаковые. А нужны инкрементные. Как раз если папка НЕ существует. Что он и пытается проверить. Для своей базы данных на ~пальцах~ файлах. Вы пишете миллион комментариев вместо того, чтобы один раз подумать.

Comment: Откуда берется `$id` которое Вы подставляете в скрытый input? Или из этого условия `if(empty($id))` где Вы устанавливаете его как 1?

Comment: @Simon ну вот же он, "генерируется" выше в скрипте.

Comment: @Ипатьев Да я подумал может какого-то кода недостает